# Turning off word-wrap with less during paging?

Tags: text-formatting, less, wrap

I can get the effect that I want from running `less -S` but it seems fishy to me that there is no way to render the input without word-wrap after the file is opened.

Is there anyway to

```
less /tmp/longtext
```

And then after you have it up to disable wordwrap without exiting and restarting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside `less`, press <kbd>-</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd>.

This technique is applicable generally in `less`: <kbd>-</kbd> will toggle the command-line option corresponding to the next key pressed.